# Can i run a program in C# for Lego NXT with wifi connection?

Tags: nxt

I would like to run a program in C # using a wifi connection. I found a wireless sensor, WifiBlock, which can connect to the NXT and connect to the PC. But I don't know if Wifiblock can run a program in C#. Do you know other sensor that can do it or know if Wifiblock can?

Thanks and sorry for my english, i'm spanish :S

Javier.